# Deleting all files in temp folder Using python

Tags: python, shutil

This is my code to delete temp folder all files but as temp files are being used, I want to skip all the files which can't be deleted and delete rest all the files.
Could anyone suggest me the better code?

```
def del_tmp_files():
    username = getpass.getuser()
    del_path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
    shutil.rmtree(del_path)
    print("Del Path" + del_path)
    return
```

Comment: Have you tried `shutil.rmtree(del_path, ignore_errors=True)` ?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree

Answer (score 1):

Use *`ignore_errors=True`* with `shutil.rmtree`.

**`def rmtree(path, ignore_errors=False, onerror=None):`**

> Recursively delete a directory tree.
>
> ```
> If ignore_errors is set, errors are ignored; otherwise, if onerror
> is set, it is called to handle the error with arguments (func,
> path, exc_info) where func is platform and implementation dependent;
> path is the argument to that function that caused it to fail; and
> exc_info is a tuple returned by sys.exc_info().  If ignore_errors
> is false and onerror is None, an exception is raised.
> ```

```
import getpass
import shutil

def del_tmp_files():
    username = getpass.getuser()
    del_path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
    shutil.rmtree(del_path, ignore_errors=True)
    print("Del Path" + del_path) 
    return

del_tmp_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the try except framework to delete files, and here is pseudo code:

```
cd temp directory
fileList = get all the filenames in the temp directory
for file in fileList:
  try:
    delete file
  except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from getpass import getuser
from shutil import rmtree
from os import walk , remove

def del_tmp_files():
    username = getuser()
    del_path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
    for path, subdirs, files in walk(del_path):
        for name in files:
            file_path = path + '\\' + name
            try:
                remove(file_path)
            except:
                pass
        for name_dir in subdirs:
            dir_path = path + '\\' + name_dir
            try:
                rmtree(dir_path)
            except:
                pass
```